# last_login does not update by API in django rest

Tags: django-rest-framework

I created a simple endpoint to create and update users. It's work fine except for the field last_login that not update when a user login by API.

My example:

My urls:

```
router.register(r"user", foo.UserViewSet)
```

My Serializer:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],
            email=validated_data["email"],
            last_login=validated_data["last_login"],
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = (
            "groups",
            "user_permissions",
        )
```

My View:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    pagination_class = StandardPagination
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    model = User

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            user, data=request.data, partial=True
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I log with any user (in API) the field last_login is always null. By django admin is ok.

#### Update

I had some progress and problems putting the code in my UserViewSet:

```py
    def perform_authentication(self, request):
        user = request.user
        user.last_login = timezone.now()
        user.save()
        return user
```

Ok. last_login is registering, but only in user endpoint and every request in this endpoint.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `User.objects.update(last_login=request.data["last_login"])`? Also, did you check if you were sending in the `last_login` value in your update request?

Comment: @sliderIt was just an attempt to put value. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

As far as my own investigation on this issue goes, it turns out that last_login field is tightly coupled with default Django authentication system (session authentication), that is why this field is updated when you use Django Admin, as Admin uses session authentication.

In your case, it looks like some other type of authentication is used, and the signal which updates this field is not triggered. See the link below where the signal is handled:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/5f8495a40ab1554e81ac845484da890dd390e1d8/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L14

So, in order to update this field properly you should probably do it manually.
Here is one more discussion on this matter:
[last_login field is not updated when authenticating using Tokenauthentication in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613102/last-login-field-is-not-updated-when-authenticating-using-tokenauthentication-in)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be the default setting, try this in settings.py:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    // ... 
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': True,
    // ...
}
```

source: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html